# Applying color to cell range in aspose not working

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

Trying to apply foregroundcolor to cell range but it is getting applied to whole column range
I have created a second sheet as below and applying color by creating an extension method on cell range.

```
package.Worksheets.Add("AutoITC Accepted Report");
Worksheet worksheet2 = package.Worksheets[1];
worksheet2.Cells.CreateRange("A1:D1").ApplyHeaderColor("grey");
worksheet2.Cells.CreateRange("E1:W1").ApplyHeaderColor("yellow");
```

The custom extension method "ApplyHeaderColor()" is as below:

```
 public static Range ApplyHeaderColor(this Range cellRange,string color)
 {
  CellsFactory cellsFactory = new CellsFactory();
  Style _style = cellsFactory.CreateStyle();
  _style.Pattern = BackgroundType.Solid;
  switch (color)
        {
            case "smoke":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(191, 191, 191);
                break;
            case "graphite":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(237, 237, 237);
                break;
            case "grey":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 242);
                break;
            case "crimson":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 250);
                break;
            case "yellow":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 204);
                break;
            case "lemon":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(252, 228, 214);
                break;
            case "green":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(226, 239, 218);
                break;
            case "blue":
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(217, 225, 242);
                break;
            default:
                _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 242);
                break;
        }
        StyleFlag flag = new StyleFlag();
        flag.All = true;
        cellRange.ApplyStyle(_style,flag);
        return cellRange;
    }
```

color is applied to whole of excel selected column:
[image]

expected outcome should be only header row as below:
[image]

Seems like cell range is not picked properly,please help to identify the mistake in aspose code.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your scenario/case using your sample code (I did update a bit as following) and it works fine, I do not find your mentioned issue.

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```cs
Workbook package = new Workbook();
package.Worksheets.Add("AutoITC Accepted Report");            
Worksheet worksheet2 = package.Worksheets[1];
//Input some values to the worksheet cells
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j <= 25; j++)
        {
           worksheet2.Cells[i, j].PutValue("Data " + i + "," + j);
        }                
   }
Range range = worksheet2.Cells.CreateRange("A1:D1");
ApplyHeaderColor(range,  "grey");
Range range1 = worksheet2.Cells.CreateRange("E1:W1");
ApplyHeaderColor(range1,  "yellow");
package.Save("e:\\test2\\out1.xlsx");

..........

void ApplyHeaderColor(Range cellRange, string color)
{
            CellsFactory cellsFactory = new CellsFactory();
            Style _style = cellsFactory.CreateStyle();
            _style.Pattern = BackgroundType.Solid;
            switch (color)
            {
                case "smoke":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(191, 191, 191);
                    break;
                case "graphite":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(237, 237, 237);
                    break;
                case "grey":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 242);
                    break;
                case "crimson":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 250);
                    break;
                case "yellow":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 204);
                    break;
                case "lemon":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(252, 228, 214);
                    break;
                case "green":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(226, 239, 218);
                    break;
                case "blue":
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(217, 225, 242);
                    break;
                default:
                    _style.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 242);
                    break;
            }
            StyleFlag flag = new StyleFlag();
            flag.All = true;
            cellRange.ApplyStyle(_style, flag); 
}
```

Please find attached the screenshot of the output Excel file for your reference.
[image]
I guess your issue lies in your own code. So, kindly do evaluate and debug it. You should be able to fix it accordingly. In case you still find the issue,  kindly do share complete standalone sample code (same as I shared above) to reproduce the issue. I can check it soon.

By the way, you may also post your queries or issue in the dedicated [forums](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.